# How to bind the Command Timeout to an dbml (Linq-To-Sql data class)?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, database-connection

I know that we cannot set the Command Timeout in the Connection String. So I put it in the MyDataContext constructor. But there are many constructors, **this file is usually overwritten by the visual designer** and it doesn't seems the right way to do that. How would you do that?

Answer (score 6):

I was putting the code in the constructor, but the right way to do that is to create a separate file and paste the code below:

```
partial class DataClassesDataContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        this.CommandTimeout = Settings.Default.CommandTimeout;
    }
}
```